# Deleteing all entries in a DomainUpDown control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a domainUpDown control and I want to be able to do a complete refresh on it's contents, i.e. delete everything in it and add all new entries.

How do I delete all the contents of the control?

Chuck

Comment: Thank-you to Grant and Selman22 for the answer. That was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying "DomainUpDownItemCollection" is derived from "ArrayList", so you can call any method on it that you could call on other collections, including `Clear()`:

```
domainUpDown1.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `Items.Clear` method:

```
domainUpDown1.Items.Clear();
```